# MongoDB multi server mode

Tags: mongodb, replication

We have two application servers in two different geographical locations. The load balancer automatically sends clients to the closest server, unless that server is down, then all clients are sent to the only available one. Both servers are reading and writing data.
Each server is running an application and a database instance. The application on each server is only accessing the local database and doesn't know anything about the other server.
Currently, we are using MySQL with master-master replication, so both servers share the same data in the database. Primary keys are auto-increment number with one server using even numbers and the second one odd numbers.
We would like to add MongoDB instance to each server and keep similar approach for redundancy and availability. As MongoDB does not natively support master-master replication, is there a way to create a sharded replica set, so each server stores a shard, but both servers are replicated so both shards are available to each server?
Is there a way to created the desired behavior, so each application only accessing the local MongoDB instance, but the data from both servers will be available on each of the servers?

Comment: MongoDB replication and sharding are two different concepts. A shard is typically a replica-set by itself. You can use either a replication solution or a sharding solution. In case of a replica-set your application connects to the replica-set. In case of a sharded cluster the application connects to a `mongos`. See [MongoDB - FAQs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/) on these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clearly distinct between "Replication" and "Sharing"

Replication means you have several nodes. You have **one** PRIMARY and one or several SECONDARY. As term "repliaction" implies the SECONDARY have an **exact** copy of the PRIMARY. An application can write **only** to the PRIMARY, however it can read either from PRIMARY or SECONDARY.

Sharding means you distribute the data over several nodes. In your case you put even ID's to one node and odd ID's to the other node. This is very similar to MongoDB sharding, however typically you just define the sharding key and MongoDB takes care how to distribute the data evenly. Like in your current setup, when one shard/node goes down, then half of your customer has no access to their data.

Note, each shard itself is also a replica set, however it is possible to create replica sets with just one member (i.e. just the PRIMARY and no SECONDARY). Of course, the availability would be limited but that's the same as you have in your current setup.

In order to get the same setup as your current design you would build a sharded cluster. Each shard would be build by a single-member Replica set. The Config-Servers would be a replica set on both nodes.

If one node goes down then the config becomes read-only, so typically your application is still available (to half of your customers) but you cannot make modifications like create new users or collections.

Comment: This approach will not solve the problem. When the "so" primary server goes down, all users will be directed to the other server and it must be read-write.

Comment: Then it would be a replica set.